# Can't get a:hover function in CSS to work

Tags: html, css, hover

For some reason my browser with xampp (PHP) isn't giving a response when hovering in this piece of code. how can I solve this to get my text get a different color while hovering over with my mouse?

```
.headermenu a{
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block 5px;
    background-color: #7f2048;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #888888;
    border-radius: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 24px;
    padding-right: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 
.headermenu a: hover{
    color: #5b5a64;
}
```

---

I'm using `<div class="headermenu">` and a end-div to get it to work.

In Sublime Text the text hover from `.headermenu a:hover{}` is white so means not functioning or something i guess.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You have a space between `a:` and `hover. It's probably that. - Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Nothing to do with php, purely html / css.

Comment: CSS doesn't have "functions" or "commands" hover is an element state and `:hover` is a pseudo-selector. Also the correct syntax is `a:hover` (no spaces) to indicate anchor in the hover state.

Answer (score 1):

Complete braces in `.headermenu a` class css.

```css
.headermenu a{
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block 5px;
    background-color: #7f2048;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #888888;
    border-radius: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 24px;
    padding-right: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    border :1px solid black;
}
.headermenu a:hover {
    color: #5b5a64;
}
```

```html
<div class="headermenu"><a href="" >aaa</a></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

for some reason thats not solving the hover issue. i have a if else structure that starts the complete php site, i don't know if  that can have anything to do with it...?

```css
.headermenu a{
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block 5px;
    background-color: #7f2048;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #888888;
    border-radius: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 24px;
    padding-right: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    border :1px solid black;
}
.headermenu a:hover {
    color: #5b5a64;
}
```

```html
<div class="headermenu"><a href="" >aaa</a></div>
```

Comment: css directly copied from below answer?